# I can't get rid of the Ctrl-Shift-Alt Bubble

Tags: windows-8.1, tablet

I have this same problem:

> [How do I turn off the little CTRL-SHIFT bubble that pops up on Windows 7 around my cursor?](https://superuser.com/questions/59816/how-do-i-turn-off-the-little-ctrl-shift-bubble-that-pops-up-on-windows-7-around)

But I'm using Windows 8.1, and there is no "Tablet PC".

The `regedit.exe` method also does not work, because there is no `UIButtonMode`

I've tried every step in the link but it didn't work out.

Comment: Does it go away when you logout or reboot? What seems to cause it?

Comment: it only pop-up when i hold Ctrl, Alt or Shift while using my pen

Answer (score 0):

~ Right click Desktop > Personalize 
~ Click Change mouse pointers 
~ Pointer options Tab
~ Uncheck "Show location of pointer when I press CTRL key"

[image]